# How/where to download large amount of patent applications?

Tags: epo, bulk-download

I am trying to find out how/where I can download large amount of patent application data. I'm particularly interested in readable data e.g. XML rather than PDF files which can be processed by machines. I've seen [this question](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/14449/where-to-do-download-patents-data) but it's linking to US patent data whereas I'd be interested to get data from the European Patent Office (EPO).

Since one can object a patent application if it collides with one of his or her own I hope there is an easy way to download large amounts of patents from a particular category/group.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The EPO offers bulk download of patents through their Open Patent Services.  It provides this information in XML format.  It does require some technical skills but not overly complex. It is free up to a point, but may place restrictions depending on the amount of data to be downloaded.
  http://www.epo.org/searching-for-patents/technical/espacenet/ops/faq.html#faq-64

http://www.epo.org/searching-for-patents/technical/espacenet/ops.html#tab1

You can categorize relevant documents through their CPC codes or industrial codes.   There are several sources of information on determining the appropriate CPC code.

https://www.uspto.gov/web/patents/classification/cpc.html
http://www.cooperativepatentclassification.org/index.html;jsessionid=1r0o2vu3ol2jo