# Are patent applications publicly available?

Tags: patent-applications, provisional-application, united-states, bulk-download, resources

Are patent applications of pending patents publicly available? If so, can they be download somewhere?

Comment: You might want to seach this site with the bulk-download tag. Here are some relevant questions: https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/17321/how-where-to-download-large-amount-of-patent-applications and https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/14449/where-to-do-download-patents-data. Personally I like this site: https://www.lens.org/lens/new-search?type=PATENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, most are publicaly available from the USPTO and google patents. I believe google has a way of bulk access. Unless non-publication is selected by the applicant, they are published at 18 months after the earliest claimed priority document. Most other countries do not allow non-publication. The 18 month publication date is uniform internationally.

Comment: I generally find The Lens to be more reliable and featured than google patents do I like to mention it in my answers.